# Condition number for non-negative least squares

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, condition-number

If I want to analyze the stability of a non-negative least squares problem $||Ax-b||_2^2, x\ge0$, how can I measure the stability of the system? If it was a regular least squares problem, then I can compute the condition number of $A$, however, this doesn't extend to the non-negative LS case because of the constraint. My goal is to determine which $A$ out of different options is the best for this problem for some experiment.
Thank you.

Comment: That's a good question. I would start with the KKT first-order necessary conditions for optimality. However, due to the inequality constraint $x\geq 0$, the conditions for optimality will be nonlinear which complicates matters.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I was thinking about things related to the dual problem but wasn't able to get anything useful. From KKT we get $A^T A x = A^T b +\lambda$. However, I don't know how to get some conditions on A from that. I also don't mind the condition depending on some $\lambda \ge 0$, since I'll be optimizing on that anyway, so I can try different $\lambda$ values. Do you have any direction in this case?